# strange foreign key constraint violation in child table when selecting if from parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

NOTE: the book's id is its title

```
insert ignore into category_book 
select 1 as user_id, 'name' as category_name, b.id as book_id 
from book b 
where b.id regexp('word') AND b.id IS NOT NULL
```

I get:

> MySQL error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`book`.`category_book`, CONSTRAINT `fk_category_book_book1` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `book` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: What is the defintion of `category_book`? Are your columns in the correct order? It is **always** a good idea to explicitly list the columns you are inserting to, it will future proof your code against any schema changes as well as making immediately obvious to anyone reading your code what is being inserted to where.

Comment: Are you _sure_ `category_book` has the fields `user_id,category_name, book_id` _in that order_? Naming them in the select does little, you might want to specify `INSERT INTO category_book (user_id, category_name, book_id) SELECT ...`

Comment: we fixed the problem, which was that we have the column order in the select statement wrong, it should have been book_id, category_name, user_id.

@Wrikken Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Which is why explicitly naming them in the query is better then just relying on a certain order of fields.

Comment: Although directed at SQL Server, a lot of the points in this article are transferrable - [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * - omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to insert a record into category_book whose its book_id does not exists in the table books. It could be that the order category_book columns is not the same that the ones that you are providing in the select. Try the same query but indicating the columns in the insert clause.